# UIAlertController subclass issue swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I want to create a UIAlertController's subclass but I'm going crazy because I have problem with constructor, this is my subclass:

```
class loginAlert :  UIAlertController {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

}
```

I think that this subclass must have the constructor : 
UIAlertController(title: String, message: String, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle) , because it's a subclass of UIAlertController , but when I do

```
loginAlert(title: "test", message: "test", preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

I get error , why where Do I wrong?

Comment: what's the error ? why do you want to subclass UIAlertController ?

Comment: because I want to create a standard uialertController that I use a lot in my code

Comment: You can, in fact, subclass `UIAlertController` and customize some of its private properties if you wish.  Just note that Apple checks for private property and API use when submitting to the store:  http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIAlertController

Comment: sorry , what do you mean when say that Apple checks private property?

Answer (score 19):

From the [UIAlertController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014538-CH1-SW2):

> Subclassing Notes The UIAlertController class is intended to be used
>   as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this
>   class is private and must not be modified.

You can create a view controller whose view contains transparency and whose UIModalPresentationStyle is .OverCurrentContext and UIModalTransitionStyle is .CrossDissolve for a very similar effect.

Or you can write an extension on UIAlertController that can add methods that need to be shared across classes (e.g. a method that presents a reoccurring alert). For more information about extensions, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html).

Comment: ok , but if I want to create a standard alert controller , because I must use the same in my code

Comment: If it's standard, why are you subclassing?

Comment: For an overview of how to use UIAlertController see here: http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/

Comment: what about a func creating the alert ?

Comment: in my code , in various point of code , I must call the same uialertcontroller with the same buttons and actions , for this reason I would to create a "personal" uiAlertController adding in the class the the actions and all, so to call only the constructor in the all points I need it

Comment: You can write an extension on UIAlertController that can add methods and computed values.

Comment: yes I thought about function but where? because I need of uialert in different class

Comment: For more information about extensions see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

function that create a UIAlertController outside a class

```
public  func alert () {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "I don't feel creative", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    // As many action as you want
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

but as beyowulf said you can use an extension if you want to add method to UIAlertController